# Snowflake - Failure using stage area. Cause: [The AWS Access Key Id you provided is not valid.]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task, snowflake-pipe

I'm trying to connect to my personal S3 bucket using Snowflake. First of all, i used the url, aws key id and secret key to create the stage (Success). But when i tried to list the s3 bucket, i got the following error -

Failure using stage area. Cause: [The AWS Access Key Id you provided is not valid.]

I am sure i've typed in the correct credentials, any idea why this error appears?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure that those credentials have access to the S3 bucket that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I pulled those credentials using the STS method and i got the access key id, secret key id and Session Token.

Comment: That makes the key valid, but doesn't necessarily provide the correct permissions to the S3 bucket.  I would double-check that you have the correct permissions setup to that key in AWS IAM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem but that was happened when I created a staging for Azure Blob. There I missed to provide the List Permission to list the files. Please check in your AWS IAM roles that you have permissions to list the files in s3. 
Maybe this might help you.

Thanks